# Wikipedia API Autocomplete with Json

Tags: jquery, jsonp, jquery-autocomplete, wikipedia-api

How can I implement it in the jQuery Autocomplete?

```
    $("#searchForm input").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    maxRows: 10,
                },
            });
        },

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:**

if you look at [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), you'll see a remote call with jsonp example

look at the source of their example and the `sucess` function. It looks like they are mapping the jsonp fields to use the data as needed for the autocomplete. use fiddler to see the json coming down from their example.

```
success: function( data ) {
 response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
```

Comment: so does that answer your question or do you still need help? if this answered your question please mark it as such. thanks

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. Answering by letting me know to read something that ive mentioned that I read already, doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I still need help because it doesn't parse anything.

Comment: see my edit, let me know if that helps better. I did completely miss the part where you mentioned you were using jquery ui autocomplete.